# Spring Integration tests with queue channels

Tags: spring, testing, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In Spring Integration I have a DSL setup that looks something like this:

```
                                       --->                                        --->
                                       --->                                        --->
Messages --> Gateway ---> QueueChannel ---> MessageHandler(worker) -> QueueChannel ---> MH worker2 --> ...
                                       --->                                        --->
                                       --->                                        --->
```

I want to write an integration test for that, which will test if the message was in proper channels. I do not enrich headers right now anywhere, so I wanted to use:

```
this.someChannel.receive(TIMEOUT)
```

unfortunately, as I understand, it is blocking only the main thread of test, not all, so it cannot receive any message sent asynchronously. 
I know, that there exists something like:

```
this.someChannel.getReceiveCount()
```

it gives me good results, but checking it is not enough for me.
How can I deal with it, to receive messages sent to queues in async way?

EDIT: It is important, that I need it, because the message is changed during going through workflow

Answer (score 0):

You can add a channel interceptor to those queue channels in the test to track whatever comes through those channels. Of course you need to have in the test some barrier to wait for asynchronous messages or just blocking queue to gather them for verification in the end of test. Another way is to mock or spy message handlers in between, but again with similar `CountDownLatch` or `BlockingQueue` thread barrier to wait for asynchronous messages. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html#test-context